# How to save steps after clicking on List Items

Tags: java, android

First of all sorry if the title is not suitable for my case,first I have a list view in fragment which have an adapter class components my list is looks like this [image: sample],thats if I click on menu Item it will increase the quantity by every click thats shown in that small orange box,my problem is that when I scroll this list or even change the activity it doesn't save the click that I did like this [image: Sample 2] the quantity is backed to 0,all I need I just want to save this clicked action as
this is my adapter class

```
package abtech.waiteriano.com.waitrer.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import abtech.waiteriano.com.waitrer.R;
import abtech.waiteriano.com.waitrer.fragments.LVMenuFragment;

/**
 * Created by dell on 3/7/2017.
 */

public class CustomMenuLVAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<String> resultMenuItems;
    LVItemHolder lvItemHolder;
    Context context;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public CustomMenuLVAdapter(LVMenuFragment lvMenuFragment, ArrayList<String> listMenuArray) {
        resultMenuItems = listMenuArray;
        context = lvMenuFragment.getActivity();
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return resultMenuItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public class LVItemHolder {
        TextView listMenuTV, txtQTY;
        RelativeLayout qtyView;
        Button minusBtn;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final LVItemHolder lvItemHolder = new LVItemHolder();
        View rowView;
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_list_item, null);
        lvItemHolder.listMenuTV = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.menulistTV2);
        lvItemHolder.txtQTY = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtQTY);
        lvItemHolder.minusBtn = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.minusBtn);
        lvItemHolder.listMenuTV.setText(resultMenuItems.get(position));
        lvItemHolder.txtQTY.setText("0");
        rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int q = 0;
                q = Integer.valueOf(lvItemHolder.txtQTY.getText().toString());
                q++;
                lvItemHolder.txtQTY.setText("" + q);
//                Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+resultMenuItems.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        lvItemHolder.minusBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int q = 0;
                q = Integer.valueOf(lvItemHolder.txtQTY.getText().toString());
                if (q > 0)
                    q--;
                lvItemHolder.txtQTY.setText("" + q);
            }
        });
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

this is my Activity

```
package abtech.waiteriano.com.waitrer.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import abtech.waiteriano.com.waitrer.MenuActivity;
import abtech.waiteriano.com.waitrer.R;
import abtech.waiteriano.com.waitrer.adapters.CustomMenuLVAdapter;
import abtech.waiteriano.com.waitrer.connection_class.ConnectionClass;

public class LVMenuFragment extends android.app.Fragment {
    View rootView;
    ListView menuListView;
    public static ArrayList<String> listMenuArray = new ArrayList<String>();


    public LVMenuFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lvmenu, container, false);
        menuListView=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listMenuArray.clear();
       String menuListSTR = "";
        if (MenuActivity.Prst_ID.trim() == "-1")
            menuListSTR = "Select ID,Code,Name,Name2 From Presets Where Active = 1 And Rest_ID_Active = 1 AND OutLet_ID_Active = 1 ORDER BY Code";
        else
            menuListSTR = "select dbo.MenuItems.Item_ID, dbo.Items.Code, dbo.Items.Name, dbo.Items.Name2, dbo.Items.PrintOnChick, dbo.Items.Taxable, dbo.Items.NoServiceCharge, dbo.Items.PrintOnReport,Case { fn IFNULL ((SELECT Price_Value FROM dbo.ItemsPrices WHERE (PriceLVL_ID = 1) AND (Item_ID = dbo.Items.ID)), 0) } when 0 then dbo.Items.StaticPrice Else { fn IFNULL ((SELECT Price_Value FROM dbo.ItemsPrices WHERE (PriceLVL_ID = 1) AND (Item_ID = dbo.Items.ID)), dbo.Items.StaticPrice) } END AS Price From dbo.MenuItems LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Items ON dbo.MenuItems.Item_ID = dbo.Items.ID Where  (dbo.MenuItems.Preset_ID = " + MenuActivity.Prst_ID + ") AND (dbo.MenuItems.Rest_ID_Active = " + ConnectionClass.Rest_ID + ") AND (dbo.MenuItems.OutLet_ID_Active = " + ConnectionClass.OutletID + ") AND (dbo.Items.Active = 1) ORDER BY dbo.MenuItems.SortNumber";

        ResultSet rs = ConnectionClass.Ret_RS(menuListSTR);
        try {
            while (rs.next()) {
                listMenuArray.add(rs.getString("Name"));

            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        menuListView.setAdapter(new CustomMenuLVAdapter(this,listMenuArray));

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

Sorry if any thing is unclear

Comment: Can you post your activity too? I think you forget customMenuLVAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();

Comment: @msecilmis I posted my activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
public class CustomMenuLVAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
ArrayList<String> resultMenuItems;
LVItemHolder lvItemHolder;
Context context;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>;

public CustomMenuLVAdapter(LVMenuFragment lvMenuFragment, ArrayList<String> listMenuArray) {
    resultMenuItems = listMenuArray;
    context = lvMenuFragment.getActivity();
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return resultMenuItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public class LVItemHolder {
    TextView listMenuTV, txtQTY;
    RelativeLayout qtyView;
    Button minusBtn;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final LVItemHolder lvItemHolder = new LVItemHolder();
    View rowView;
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_list_item, null);
    lvItemHolder.listMenuTV = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.menulistTV2);
    lvItemHolder.txtQTY = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtQTY);
    lvItemHolder.minusBtn = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.minusBtn);
    lvItemHolder.listMenuTV.setText(resultMenuItems.get(position));

    if(map.containsKey(position)){
          lvItemHolder.txtQTY.setText(""+map.get(position));
    }else{
        lvItemHolder.txtQTY.setText("0");
     } 

    rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int q = 0;
            q = Integer.valueOf(lvItemHolder.txtQTY.getText().toString());
            q++;
            lvItemHolder.txtQTY.setText("" + q);
           map.put(position,q)
           //                Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+resultMenuItems.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    lvItemHolder.minusBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int q = 0;
            q = Integer.valueOf(lvItemHolder.txtQTY.getText().toString());
            if (q > 0)
                q--;
            lvItemHolder.txtQTY.setText("" + q);
            map.put(position,q)
        }
    });
    return rowView;
}
```

Comment: there's something wrong here     HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>;?

Comment: says that Canot Infor Arguments

Comment: put this HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

Comment: it should be like this I think     HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

Answer (score 0):

in your adapter have a funtion like the following as an example;

```
public void setNumber(int number) {this.number = number}
```

Then when the user clicks on an item to increase it, you can save it by calling this setNumber function.

```
resultMenuItems.get(position).setNumber(//you number inputed here//);
//Then call notifydatasetChanged on your adapter//
```

Just make sure that the number is then gotten through a getter function in the apater.

I hope this makes sense

Comment: Ok Thanks alot I gonna try this

Comment: sorry could you explain more how to use this function?

Comment: hot to put this in ma adapter class @Janwilx72